# How to use the Angular-nvd3 in an Angular JS project?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Okay so I came across [this](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3) on Angular-nvd3 on Github. As per my project requirements this is what I need right now. But since I have just started learning Angular JS I can't understand the steps to use nvd3 in an angular js project. Especially the basic usage part where I have to inject nvd3 directive in angular module. I want to show various charts in different components. Can anybody explain the steps after the Install section. Also if there is any Angular JS project where it has used nvd3, sharing the link to that project will also be of great help.
As shown in the picture below i want to show a bar chart in ghbar component. So to achieve that where shall I inject the dependency for nvd3? And i have several other components which will show various other charts too.
Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the dependency to nvd3 in your module. You haven't provided any code so I can't see what you've tried. From the documentation you linked there's an example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3']) // <-- this line here
   .controller('myCtrl', function('$scope'){
       /* code */
    })
```

Once the library has been injected you will be able to access the directives in your HTML. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well this is where i am facing the problem. I am just a beginner and do not know how to inject the dependency. Should i write this piece of code in app.module.ts? or the ts file of the individual component?

Comment: @AlapanBag You can do either. If you only need it in a single component than inject it there. Otherwise to have it available across your app inject it in the main app.module.ts.